# Image does not display on webpage React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have create 2 files one is **data.js** and **slider.js** I want to take data from data.js and use in slider.js other items Title & desc are working fine and I am actually new to react so it would be a great if you guys can help me understand and correct my mistakes Thank you!

```
//This is data.js

export const sliderItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img: "",
      title: "FANTASTIC PRESALE",
      desc: "SAVE BIG ON ABS GAMING SYSTEMS High Refresh Rate Monitors & other hardware components! Upto 60% Off",
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      img: "../images/img2.png",
      title: "Title 2",
      desc: "Desc 2",
      
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      img: "../images/img2.png",
      title: "Title 3",
      desc: "Desc 3",
    },
  ];
```

**slider.js**

```
const Slider = () => {
    const [sideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = (direction) => {

    };
  return (
    <Container>
        <Arrow direction="left" onClick={()=>handleClick("left")}>
        <ArrowLeftOutlined />
        </Arrow>
        <Wrapper>
            {sliderItems.map(item=>(
            <Slide >
            <ImgContainer>
            <Image src={item.img}/>
            </ImgContainer>
            <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{item.title}</Title>
                <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
                <Button>SHOP NOW</Button>
            </InfoContainer>
            </Slide>
            ))};
        </Wrapper>
        <Arrow direction="right" onClick={()=>handleClick("right")}>
        <ArrowRightOutlined/>
        </Arrow>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Since you have separate Image Component, you will need to import an image into a constant variable inside ImgContainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `require()` on image path, try this.

```
export const sliderItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img: "",
      title: "FANTASTIC PRESALE",
      desc: "SAVE BIG ON ABS GAMING SYSTEMS High Refresh Rate Monitors & other hardware components! Upto 60% Off",
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      img: require("../images/img2.png"),
      title: "Title 2",
      desc: "Desc 2",
      
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      img: require("../images/img2.png"),
      title: "Title 3",
      desc: "Desc 3",
    },
  ];
```

or you can also do like this:

```
import Image1 from "../images/img2.png";
import Image2 from "../images/img2.png";

export const sliderItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "",
    title: "FANTASTIC PRESALE",
    desc: "SAVE BIG ON ABS GAMING SYSTEMS High Refresh Rate Monitors & other hardware components! Upto 60% Off",
    
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: Image1,
    title: "Title 2",
    desc: "Desc 2",
    
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: Image2,
    title: "Title 3",
    desc: "Desc 3",
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks Brother! The Second one worked!!